# Search through a list of strings for a word that has a variable character

Tags: python, list, search

Basically, I start with inserting the word "brand" where I replace a single character in the word with an underscore and try and find all words that match the remaining characters. For example:

"b_and" would return: "band", "brand", "bland" .... etc.

I started with using re.sub to substitute the underscore in the character. But I'm really lost on where to go next. I only want words that are different by this underscore, either without the underscore or by replacing it with a letter. Like if the word "under" was to run through the list, i wouldn't want it to return "understood" or "thunder", just a single character difference. Any ideas would be great!

I tried replacing the character with every letter in the alphabet first, then back checking if that word is in the dictionary, but that took such a long time, I really want to know if there's a faster way

```
from itertools import chain

dictionary=open("Scrabble.txt").read().split('\n')

import re,string

#after replacing the word with "_", we find words in the dictionary that match the pattern
    new=[]
    for letter in string.ascii_lowercase:
        underscore=re.sub('_', letter, word)
        if underscore in dictionary:
            new.append(underscore)
    if new == []:
        pass
    else:
        return new
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC this should do it. I'm doing it outside a function so you have a working example, but it's straightforward to do it inside a function.

```
string = 'band brand bland cat dand bant bramd branding blandisher'
word='brand'
new=[]
for n,letter in enumerate(word):
    pattern=word[:n]+'\w?'+word[n+1:]
    new.extend(re.findall(pattern,string))
new=list(set(new))
```

Output:

```
['bland', 'brand', 'bramd', 'band']
```

Explanation:

We're using `regex` to do what you're looking. In this case, in every iteration we're taking one letter out of "brand" and making the algorithm look for any word that matches. So it'll look for:

_rand, b_and, br_nd, bra_d, bran_

For the case of "b_and" the pattern is `b\w?and`, which means: find a word with b, then any character may or may not appear, and then 'and'.

Then it adds to the list all words that match.

Finally I remove duplicates with `list(set(new))`

Edit: forgot to add `string` vairable.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version of Juan C's answer that's a bit more Pythonic

```py
import re

dictionary = open("Scrabble.txt").read().split('\n')
pattern = "b_and" # change to what you need
pattern = pattern.replace('_', '.?')
pattern += '\\b'

matching_words = [word for word in dictionary if re.match(pattern, word)]
```

Edit: fixed the regex according to your comment, quick explanation:

```py
pattern = "b_and"
pattern = pattern.replace('_', '.?') # pattern is now b.?and, .? matches any one character (or none at all)
pattern += '\\b' # \b prevents matching with words like "bandit" or words longer than "b_and"
```

Comment: this is great, but how can i only get results for words that are different by a single character? i'm getting results with 'blandished', 'blandisher', 'blandishers', i want only the single character difference

Comment: I added '\b' to mine, which I believes solves your issue